# How Yoast SEO plugin works with variable %%name%%?

Tags: database, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I know that Yoast SEO plugin doesn't create any database table then why in wp_postmeta numbering of meta_id are not continuous?

Is it because of Yoast Plugin?

Also I want to know how its feature of automatic seo by default %%title%% in post works?

Because when I tried to use variable %%name%% with %%title%% in post type page but %%name%% appears as it is and %%title%% shows title of my page.

[image: Error]

So I want that it takes authour name as per [variable list](http://kb.yoast.com/article/146-yoast-wordpress-seo-titles-metas-template-variables) of Yoast Plugin

Comment: Yoast does not create tables.

Comment: That is how WordPress does that column by default. You should remove the second part of this and ask more thoroughly in a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not create tables, it stores data the "WordPress way" in the postmeta table, which is common to all WordPress functions.  Because it's common to all WordPress functions, the ID's are going to be out of sequence for Yoast data, because it's going to be "commingled" with much other data that gets stored in that table.

As to your question about the `%%name%%` variable, it appears you are trying to use the variable **inside your post title**, which you cannot do.  For it to work, you'd need to do something like so, *in your Titles & Meta Settings*:

`%%title%% - by %%name%%`

**IMPORTANT UPDATE**
This actually is a bug in the *preview* feature on the post (as of version 2.3.5, and up to and including version 3.0.7).  The variable `%%name%%` is NOT getting parsed properly.

However, if you view the page itself, the variables **are** being parsed properly, including the `%%name%%` variable.

Comment: As you said that i need to do so but how can i do that?

It doesn't accepting %%name%% .

I did that in meta setting only

Comment: This is for post and yes I am on local machine.

I can share screenshots

Comment: This is the situation...

http://puu.sh/mN7AX/21fa62fa5c.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34982/discussion-between-siren-brown-and-cale-b).